# Сложные inserts в БД через EF6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Есть БД с такой структурой:
[image: Структура]

Работаю с EF6.

Данные добавляются поэтапно.
Сначала добавляются данные в таблицу Case. С этим проблем нет.
Таблица LinkCaseHistory линковочная и в EF не видна.

Далее идет добавление в таблицы HistoryEvent и CaseListHistory одновременно.
HistoryEvent.Id -identity autoincrement.

В эти таблицы нужно добавить более 200.000 записей.

Вот код для добавления в EF:

```
foreach(var @case in context.Case.Where(args=>args.RNK=rnk))
{
@case.HistoryEvent.Add(new HistoryEvent
                       {
                           Date = DateTime.Now,
                           dicTypeActionId = 1,
                           UserId = currentUser,
                           CaseListHistory = new[]
                                            {
                                                new CaseListHistory
                                                {
                                                    Id=(int) @case.CaseId,
                                                    RNC=@case.RNC,
                                                    Reverted=false,
                                                    Current=false,
                                                    dicListTypeId=1,
                                                    CaseId=(int) @case.CaseId
                                                }
                                            }

                       });
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Добавление в модель и сохранение в БД занимает очень много времени.
Хотелось бы ускорить процесс сохранения в базу.

Вариант

```
   context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled=false;
```

не помогает, т.к. HistoryEvent и Case через linkCaseHistory не связывает.

Сохранение пачками по 100,1000,5000,100000 записей не делает прироста производительности.

Comment: _"Данные добавляются поэтапно."_ -- откуда берутся данные? если из файлов/датчиков и т.д., и данных много, то использование EF - лишняя трата времени. т.к. данные загружаются в память, десериализуются в объекты, затем переобразуются для передачи данных в базу, где опять преобразуются и сохраняются.

Comment: Данные берутся из других БД, абсолютно разных по структуре и содержанию и, не исключено, хранятся на разных серверах БД. И кроме импорта еще нужно мержить их по правилам определенных.

Comment: _"Данные берутся из других БД .. нужно мержить"_ и т.к. данных много, то лучше использовать DataSet - в нем есть Merge, а данные хранятся как объекты, т.е. не будет потерь на де/сериализацию. 
все DataTable's из DataSet можно загрузить в базу с помощью SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable) -- наверное так будет быстрее всего.

Comment: Может и быстрее. Но проделано уже очень много и ломать это все и начинать практически с нуля - тоже не хочется. Поэтому я и пытаюсь малой кровью отделаться.

Answer (score 2):

1. Ставите в начале `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled=false;`
2. перед `context.SaveChanges();` пишите строчку `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();`

Это **единственный** способ работать с такими объемами в EF.

Comment: Судя по всему, автору просто нужен импорт, и он решает задачу не теми средствами.

Comment: Импорт, да. Но импорт сложный. Структуры разные .

И какими же средствами Вы предлагаете импортировать данные?

Answer (score 2):

> В эти таблицы нужно добавить более 200.000 записей.
>   Добавление в модель и сохранение в БД занимает очень много времени. Хотелось бы ускорить процесс сохранения в базу.

Ускорить можно с помощью специального средства для импорта данных 
-- [BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188365(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: BulkInsert не работает как нужно. в linkCaseHistory не пишет данные, 
т.е он не видит связей.

Comment: _"он не видит связей."_ -- да. каждую таблицу надо загружать отдельно. см. [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8)

Comment: Появился вариант. HistoryEvent.Id делать не автоинкремент. Заполнять руками Id. Потом делать автоинкремент. Но возникает вопрос с linkCaseHistory. Ее EF не видит и BulkInsert невозможно выполнить.

Comment: _"linkCaseHistory. Ее EF не видит и BulkInsert невозможно выполнить"_ -- не совсем понятно. почему нельзя выполнить BulkInsert? BulkInsert никак не зависит от EF.